# Guidelines for representing sentinel values within a list

Tags: guidelines, combobox

I'm curious if anybody can point me to a list of guidelines (preferable regarding Windows Development UI design) that may help layout rules which to follow when representing sentinel or special values within a list. An example of such a value could be a **none** or **all** option within a ListBox or ComboBox control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the Windows 7 UX Guide has [some pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511484.aspx#presentation) specific to special values which they refer to as *meta-options*. The same recommendations are also made for meta-options wihtin [ComboBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511458.aspx#presentation).

> - Place options that represent All or None at the beginning of the list, regardless of sort order of the remaining items.
> - Enclose meta-options in parentheses.
> - Don't have blank list items—use meta-options instead. Users don't know how to interpret blank items, whereas the meaning of meta-options is explicit.

It's interesting that the options representing **all** are not placed in parenthesis like the **none** option is in their examples. Anybody have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I always enclose the "extra" options in parenthesis at the top of the list: (all) (any) (none)

Comment: @Bevan - Thanks for your input, this confirms Microsoft's recommendations.