# Drop down list best practice/usability

Tags: drop-down-list

We have a website with a large application containing several drop-down lists on several different pages of the app. They are not all the same - some are country selections, some are name, some are days etc. At the moment there is no consistency on how they work and I want to know if there is a 'best practice' I can put into place.

At the moment some of the drop-down list have incremental searching, some have first letter only, some have nothing, some allow you to type in the box - some don't, some allow you to click in the box, backspace and this deletes all text and so on.

Comment: This is a website... which means that you are dealing with the browser's implementation of a drop down typically. How are you customizing the controls? Are you using javascript? Flash? Java? ActiveX? Are you simply using a variety of the built in HTML controls?

Comment: A better question... could you provide cropped screenshots of some of the controls (as long as they don't contain private information)? I'm a bit puzzled because, for example, the web has no way to do a combo-box natively (where you can type arbitrary text to filter a selection from a dropdown), but it sounds like your site has that.

Comment: Allison now has 10 rep, so posting images shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm assuming that making them all consistent isn't an option?

Comment: @fitzgeraldsteele I think that's what she wants to do, but she wants to be able to quote best practice, rather than imposing an arbitrary standard.

Answer (score 1):

If the controls have different behavior, then they should have visual affordances that suggest the differences.  For example, if a drop down list allows typing to navigate items in the list, it should look like a data entry field.  Conversely, if this behavior is not supported, if should not look like a combo box.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some Microsoft guidelines for [drop-down lists and combo boxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511458.aspx). They cover which control style to use (drop-down list, combo box, listbox, etc), presentation, behaviour, default values, sizing and spacing, labels, etc., etc.

Also, see [this](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3401/guidelines-for-representing-sentinel-values-within-a-list) question about a specific aspect of dropdown list and combox box design - sentinel values ("all", "none", etc.)

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123706432) is an excellent source of good UI design advice - you could do a lot worse than incorporate it by reference into any design guidelines you implement.

Finally, here are some more Microsoft UI guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511279.aspx